# WinForm trying to commit DataGridView changes from CellValueChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, commit

I have 2 Forms written in C# 4.0. FormA has a DataGridView hooked up to a MS SQL Database with a DataAdapter and a BindingSource. The grid has a checkbox. When the user ticks the checkbox FormB is called. FormB has a "yes"/ "no" buttons. If DialogResult from FormB is "Yes" the Database should be updated with the new value of the checkbox - without the user pressing any additional items on FormA.

Here is some pseudo-code:

FormA:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogRes = new FormB().ShowDialog();
        if (dialogRes == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
             dataGridView1.EndEdit();
             table.EndInit();
             dataAdapter.Update(table);
        }
    }
```

The result is not saved to the database. If I put the same "save/update" functionality on a button event it works fine. So it must be because the CellValueChanged event needs to complete (and maybe additional events need to trigger) before I can commit the changes successfully !?

Please help, Im going nuts ...

Edit: using CellEndEdit has the same effect- which is none.
I have setup the SqlCommandBuilder, and the Database is being updated correctly in all other situations than the one described above

Comment: Try the `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` event instead of `CellValueChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at this example from MSDN on sql command Builder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx

In order for you Adapter to use the Update() methood it requires the commands setting up to perform the task. A command builder is used to generate these commands from the given Select command when you populate the data :-

```
public static DataSet SelectSqlRows(string connectionString,
    string queryString, string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        connection.Open();

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);

        //code to modify data in DataSet here

        builder.GetUpdateCommand();

        //Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
        adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);

        return dataSet;
    }
}
```